# How can I keep preferences in sync between multiple instance of my Eclipse RCP app?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, osgi

Using ConfigurationScope.INSTANCE.getNode("id").sync() will bring in changes from the other app, but it doesn't seem to call my node and preference change listeners.

Is there a way to keep settings always in sync without calling sync? It seems calling it would be prone to races.

Does sync() fire the node and preference change listeners and I'm just not noticing? If not, how can I get it to or get some similar functionality?

Comment: Are you writing to the app's config area from some other app, or are you running multiple instances of your app against the same config area? I would guess that neither are really supported.

Comment: It's from another instance of my application. I know this question is fairly general. I'm open to using a different method for storing configuration so long as it's portable. The spec doesn't say anything about it not being supported. and sync() almost does what I want. Is there another use for sync()?